# Dockerfile Struts 2

Tags: java, maven, docker, struts2

I have a struts2 project that I launch with a jetty server. I would like to make a dockerfile allowing me to create a struts2 image (to be able to launch it with a compose docker), my problem is that I have the impression that there is no documentation about struts2 to create the dockerfile, would you have some tricks to propose to me? Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Struts is part of the application scope and shouldn't be packed in a docker container by itself. It's should be packed in the EAR or Spring Boot application (for example) you are working on. You have to deploy/add the EAR or Spring Boot application to the docker image.